# Dialog box handling in excel through python

Tags: python, excel, automation, win32com

I'm automating some activities using python on excel file for insert some data in excel.  I'm trying to save the excel file after performing the required action but a dialog box appears with options ('yes' or 'no') where user attention required.
My script should select the option 'yes' of dialog box from python.

But, could not able to find proper method to do so.

Please,can someone give advice to solve this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using the libiary pywin32. I have also been confused by this several weeks ago. Here goes some sample code that eventually works.

```
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.workbooks.open(SourceFile)  # Open a workbook

# Your code to modify the excel file.
wb.RefreshAll()

# Call wb.Save() to save your changes.
wb.Save()
xl.Quit()
```

The method wb.Save() will avoid the dialog box.

You can also use SaveAs function to save the file in a new destination. Shown as below.

```
wb.SaveAs('another_workbook.xlsx')
```

Find more information on this [blog](http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/).

More hints: Sometime when I could not find a sample code for the pywin32 to operate excel, I was able to find the solution the document of VBA script. You can try this when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pywin32. You just can close the workbook with parameter 'True' to save it without asking if you want

```
wb.Close(True)
```